# GetAccountsAsync function doesn't return the data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to develop a console application that retrieves and updates user information using Microsoft Graph.

I want to use `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to retrieve the `IAccount` value.

I tried this and it couldn't retrieve any account information. I also tried to call `GetAccountAsync` to pass a correct user name also to no avail.

```
PublicClientApplication clientApp = new PublicClientApplication("xxx");

var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` until you have first called `AcquireTokenAsync`.  Once you have call that method and the user has gone through the login flow, then there will be an Account returned from `GetAccountsAsync()`.

See the example [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#how-to-get-consent-for-several-resources)

Comment: In the example you linked, it's acquiring the token `after` it calls `var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();` Same is the case in `step 2` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop#use-msal-to-get-a-token-for-the-microsoft-graph-api).

Comment: @nam Yes.  It is assumed the first time you get a token the GetAccountsAsync will return an empty list.  Future requests for a token will get the account that previously requested for a token.